# How encryption works with a QKD

Tags: cryptography, qkd

I was wondering how exactly does encryption works once you had a Quantum Key Distribution. I understand how the key is made but not how it works and I can't seems to find anyone talking about that. All I am seeing is how to make the key and that is all. Does anybody know how it is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QKD is a key distribution protocol, as given in the name, which means that it allows two (or more) parties to securely establish a shared key. It is not an encryption algorithm. The idea is that once Alice and Bob have established a shared secret key, they can then send secure communications with each other that are encrypted, for example using AES (which is a symmetric key encryption algorithm).

Comment: Using AES with QKD is a bit of a strange one. It turns the information theoretic security of QKD into computational security. If you're happy with CS in the end then why not do your key exchange with CS and avoid QKD?

Comment: It's not required that you use AES for the encryption algorithm. The point I am making is that the goal of QKD is for multiple parties to agree on a shared secret key. There are other key establishment mechanisms like Diffie-Hellman that perform the same function, but in the case of Diffie-Hellman the protocol is not post quantum secure. So, to answer your question, the reason QKD is potentially interesting is because it is (theoretically) secure under the laws of physics, whereas protocols like Diffie-Hellman are relying on computational difficulty.

Comment: You can also use the key generated by QKD as a one-time pad (OTP) instead of using AES. That makes it information theoretic secure, but limits the data rate of the encrypted data to the key generation rate of the QKD device (which is typically no more than megabits per second)

Comment: Agreed, and the security given by an OTP is very valuable. The downside of a one time pad is that it can only be used, well, one time (per the name). And QKD is not necessarily very fast / not necessarily very portable (e.g. to a non-quantum network), so using the shared key for symmetric encryption actually makes sense because you can use that key multiple times, e.g. over a non-quantum network, without needing to re-apply the QKD protocol. But again, QKD is just the key establishment mechanism, any number of subsequent encryption algorithms could be used once the shared key is established.